# i Tryed lowering My GAS fees and now my Transaction is stuck >?

Tags: gas

i Tryed sending some DENT out from my exodus wallet and i Lowered the ETH gas Fees to the point where that little Dot indicator in the Exodus wallet  turned orange ( red being the slowest ) Orange was implying it will be slow, i know it would take time but the first attempt failed and said " Dropped " so i tryed again and now its been about 4 hours and it hasn't been " Dropped " yet and is instead just stuck it seems ?

Ether scan also has not made any progress

The Transaction ID is 0x8d49e713b5b66b183c6095474976f5cf5d00bb550110631c87ed8f487ec92701 if a mod can help , i also have sent in email but no reply

is my tokens gone ? what if 20+ more hours pass and it still not returned back to my wallet?  what if it is glitched in a never ending loop

Answer (score 1):

Gas powers the transaction. The transaction consumes a certain amount of gas. Any remaining supplied (sent) gas is returned to the sender so there is no risk in sending extra gas. The transaction fails if the work cannot be completed before all the gas is gone.

GasPrice is Ether to spend per unit of gas burned. Think of it like paying $4.50/gal for gas and needed 1.6 gal for the trip. A car doesn't burn dollars directly. It burns gas and the engine is indifferent to the price paid for that gas. Consumption depends on work. The cost depends on what you paid for the gas and how much gas was burned. The amount burned depends on *work* which, in the case of an Ethereum transaction, is the nature of the transaction signed and the code that will run on the shared distributed computer.

*transaction fee (trip cost) = gas (work done) * gasPrice (bid).*

gasPrice is an offer to the miners. Miners generally prioritize transactions that pay the highest gasPrice - effectively skimming the most lucrative transactions available in the pending transaction pool, to make a block filled with gas consumption at the highest rates offered. As such, a low-priced transaction will generally not make it into a full block and may take quite a while to confirm.

In summary, gasPrice is a bid for priority and by lowering the gasPrice you have lowered the priority. There is no theoretical limit on how long it could potentially take but based on your description of what you did (yellow), it will probably confirm eventually.

Hope it helps.